# sn edges and nice empty nodes styles in forest lead to dividing by zero; what's going on?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, errors, linguistics, forest

The [`forest` manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest.pdf) defines two styles: `sn edges` and `nice empty nodes`. They are defined as:

```
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}}
```

and

```
nice empty nodes/.style={for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}} }
```

respectively.

When both of these styles are used with the following tree, I get the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: You asked me to calculate `1/0.0', but I cannot divid
e any number by zero.

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.51 \end{forest}
```

Does anybody know what is going on? How can I fix this?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}},
nice empty nodes/.style={for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} nice empty nodes, sn edges
    [TP
        [{the ball} ]
        [
            [T ]
            [PrP
                [{$<$the ball$>$} ]
                [
                    [Pr ]
                    [VoiP
                        [{$<$the ball$>$} ]
                        [
                            [Voi ]
                            [AffP
                                [{to Mary} ]
                                [
                                    [Aff ]
                                    [ThP
                                        [{$<$the ball$>$} ]
                                        [
                                            [Th ]
                                            [AgP
                                                [{by John} ]
                                                [
                                                    [Ag ]
                                                    [$\surd$throw ]
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

### Update

Interestingly, it compiles without error if everything below the `Aff` leaf is deleted. That is, the following will compile:

```
\begin{forest} nice empty nodes, sn edges
    [TP
        [{the ball} ]
        [
            [T ]
            [PrP
                [{$<$the ball$>$} ]
                [
                    [Pr ]
                    [VoiP
                        [{$<$the ball$>$} ]
                        [
                            [Voi ]
                            [AffP
                                [{to Mary} ]
                                [
                                    [Aff ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: I'm completely guessing but a coordinate doesn't have any difference between it's anchors. So it might be dividing the distance between north and south. Does it matter when you change the coordinate to node in `delay`?

Comment: @percusse You mean change `shape=coordinate` to `shape=node`? Then it throws an error `Unknown shape \`\`node.''` If you change it to `shape=rectangle`, though, it does fix the problem. That is, it will at least compile without an error, but then the tree doesn't look as I want it to look. The empty nodes show white space, rather than being connected to the next branches directly.

Comment: Yes I meant rectangle. Then keep the coordinate but change the `anchor=north` to center at the end. That should do it. If it works then you don't need that style anyway. Coordinates only have `center` anchors.

Comment: @percusse Then the spine of the tree isn't completely straight. I suppose I can live with that as a workaround though, at least for the time being.

Comment: If you use `rectangle` with inner and outer sep set to 0pt, then it is *almost* right...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I discovered that the only node in your MWE that's causing the problem is the sister of "to Mary." If you put text there, there's no error. I can't figure out why the other empty "bar-level" nodes (on the spine, between XPs) don't have the same problem, since they're coordinates too.

Comment: I took @cfr's suggestion and then tweaked a negative `outer ysep` value until it no longer threw the error. For example, for this MWE it would be `-0.550pt`. If you zoom in a lot, you can see that the lines aren't quite parallel, but when I print it I can't see the gap. The value has to be tweaked differently depending on the font, font size, and `calign angle` (e.g., `-0.455pt` is best for Linux Libertine O at 12pt with `calign angle=60`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a remark: the error occurs even without `sn edges` style.

I believe this is not a `forest`, but rather a `pgf` bug. I've tracked the problem down to `\pgfintersectionofpaths` of `pgf`'s `intersections` library. The following code replicates the exact error without `forest`.

```
\pgfintersectionofpaths{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{-3.53297pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{19.54204pt}{-31.44316pt}}%
}{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{34.6372pt}{-53.00208pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{19.54204pt}{-31.44316pt}}}
```

I've investigated the matter a bit further. `\pgfintersectionofpaths` calls  `\pgfpointintersectionoflines`, which computes the intersection of two lines by applying some coordinate transformation to some point. The mathematical details of the two "some"s in the previous sentence are not important, except for the fact that the final step in PGF's calculation of the relevant transformation matrix is inversion of some other matrix, by calling `\pgftransforminvert`.  It is `\pgftransforminvert` which fails, as the matrix it is trying to invert is near-singular. The PGF manual (p. 641) warns this will happen:

> This command will produce an error if the determinant of the matrix is too small, that is, if the matrix is near-singular.

But why is the matrix near-singular? Because the line segments we're trying to intersect are almost parallel. At this point it seemed to me as if the source of the problem was TeX's numerical precision. However ...

Before computing the intersection of lines by calling `\pgfpointintersectionoflines`, `\pgfintersectionofpaths` tries to detect if the lines intersect: this is done in the `\if`-like `\pgfiflinesintersect`. So I believe the problem is that `\pgfiflinesintersect` claims that the lines intersect, but `\pgfpointintersectionoflines` fails during the computation of the intersection. (The code of `\pgf@iflinesintersect` contains a remark "16384 may not be a robust choice.", where 16384 is a constant used in some internal normalisation process. Could this be the source of the problem?)

Investigating the behaviour of `\pgfintersectionofpaths` even further, I realized that it is actually inconsistent.  One would expect the following calls of `\pgfintersectionofpaths` to yield the same result (1 intersection, the origin):

```
\pgfintersectionofpaths
  {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0pt}}}
  {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1pt}}}
\pgfintersectionsolutions

\pgfintersectionofpaths
  {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0pt}}}
  {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-1pt}{0pt}}}
\pgfintersectionsolutions
```

However, this is not the case: the first one, where the lines are perpendicular, yields 1 intersection, the other, where the lines are (exactly) parallel, yields 0 intersections.

I would love to fix this, but the issue seems too complex for me, and anyway, I believe it deserves some discussion and that the author of `pgf` should be notified.

Comment: Huh, strange. Thanks for looking into this Sašo! Have you taken steps to notify the author of `pgf`?

Comment: Not yet, but I will.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović, any update on this? Has the author of `pgf` replied? I'd like to find out if there's a way around the bug.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović, any update on this? I can't find anything about it in the [`pgf` bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/). I would put in a bug report, but I don't think I understand the issue well enough to do it myself.

Comment: Along with @JasonZentz, I'm also wondering if there is any update on this, Sašo?

Comment: Done. As it should have been almost two years ago ...

Comment: Ah, I see that you reported the bug [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/370/). Thanks, Sašo! (cc: @JasonZentz)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this might be the case, but this error seems to be related to the font being used.

I can replicate your error when I compile your MWE using the following configurations:

- no font specification (Computer/Latin Modern), compiled with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{palatino}`, compiled with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{libertine}`, compiled with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}`, compiled with XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Doulos SIL}`, compiled with XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}`, compiled with XeLaTeX

But with these configurations, it compiles without the error:

- `\usepackage{times}`, compiled with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{kpfonts}`, compiled with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Charis SIL}`, compiled with XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Cambria}`, compiled with XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Brill}`, compiled with XeLaTeX
- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Times New Roman}`, compiled with XeLaTeX

With this one, I got a different error (Dimension too large on the `\end{forest}` line):

- `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`, compiled with XeLaTeX

So if you choose your font right, you can avoid the error. Personally, I would still prefer to have an explanation of how to avoid it regardless of font selection, though.

Comment: Huh, +1. Though I would also like to have an explanation of what's actually going on here. [Sašo said he would look into it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214856/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-around-an-entire-tree-in-forest#comment504537_214856), so hopefully an explanation is forthcoming. I'll ping him about your answer. Maybe it will help him debug.

Comment: +1 So, it seems that it is a bug in the `forest` package...