# How can I draw a circle around an entire tree in forest?

Tags: trees, forest

For some reason that I cannot discern, using `tikz={\node [draw,circle,fit to tree]{};}` to draw a circle around nodes in a tree works as expected if the nodes are embedded in a larger tree.

However, this does not work if you want to draw a circle around the entire tree:

[image]

How can I draw a circle around an entire tree with `forest`?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} baseline, sn edges
[w
    [x]
    [y, s sep=20pt
        [z]
        [a,tikz={\node [draw,circle,fit to tree]{};}
            [b]
            [c,circle,draw]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\vspace{5em}
\begin{forest} baseline, sn edges
[a,tikz={\node [draw,circle,fit to tree]{};}
    [b]
    [c,circle,draw]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a bug, and one can get it also in situations other than the entire tree; for example, set `grow=0` for nodes `w` and `y`. I'll try to fix this asap.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Sounds great. Thanks! While I have your attention, do you have any idea what's going on in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204094/sn-edges-and-nice-empty-nodes-styles-in-forest-lead-to-dividing-by-zero-whats)? `:P`

Comment: Nope ;-(  But I'll add it to my todo list as well!

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Sorry to make more work for you! `:P`

Comment: @SašoŽivanović There's [an answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216100/32888) that might help you debug and provide some insight about what's going on. It seems that changing fonts affects what's going on, oddly enough.

Comment: Found it! I forgot to save&restore `pgf`'s transformation matrix in some calculation, so, in your example, essentially x and y coordinates got switched. However, as a major new version (1.1) should be out very soon, I don't think it makes much sense for me to publish a bugfix version, especially as there are workarounds for the problem. Unless you really want it, of course!

Comment: @SašoŽivanović It's not a big deal to me if it's not fixed in the next release. Do you want to add an answer either now or when you do fix it in a future release, though?

Answer (score 7):

One option is to name some special `\node`s (the root and the lowest(s) one(s)) in the tree and then use the `fit` library with a circular `\node`:

[image]

The example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[a,name=root
  [b
    [c
      [d,name=lowestl]
      [e]
    ]
    [f ]
  ]
  [g
    [h]
    [i
      [j]
      [k,name=lowestr]
    ]
  ]
]
\node[draw,circle,fit={(root) (lowestl) (lowestr)}] {};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine the tree drawing stage to save the tree in a box and then draw the tree in a circled node.

What is nice about this is that you can define a style for this once and then just apply it to trees without having to think about their layout in order to figure out which nodes to name.

```
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
 sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}},
 circle tree/.style={
  draw tree stage/.style={
    for root'={
      draw tree box=0,
      draw tree,
      TeX={\tikz{\node [draw, circle] {\box0};}},
    }}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} baseline, sn edges, circle tree
[w
    [x]
    [y, s sep=20pt
        [z]
        [a
            [b]
            [c,circle,draw]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\vspace{5em}
\begin{forest} baseline, sn edges, circle tree
[a
    [b]
    [c,circle,draw]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: circled trees]