# Changing the size of empty nodes in forest

Tags: linguistics, forest

I want to set the following picture:

[image]

The following `forest`code almost does it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={fit=band,parent anchor=south,child anchor=north}
[ForceP
        []
        [Force$'$
                [Force$^0$]
                [TopP
                        []
                        [Top$'$
                                [Top$^0$]
                                [FocP
                                        []
                                        [Foc$'$
                                                [Foc$^0$]
                                                [TopP
                                                        []
                                                        [Top$'$
                                                                [Top$^0$]
                                                                [FinP
                                                                        []
                                                                        [Fin$'$
                                                                                [Fin$^0$]
                                                                                [IP/AgrSP]]]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

However, the arcs that go towards the left do not have the right angle:

[image]

Now, the question is: Do I have to add `\strut`s to all `empty node`s or is there a nicer way to say that the `empty node`s have the same height as their sisters to the right?

Comment: I don't get that output either, as @egreg said. Part of the code is missing? Or this is a different version?

Comment: I added the options `parent anchor=south,child anchor=north` so as to reproduce exactly the output in the picture.

Comment: @egreg This will mess up Harish Kumar's answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternative method which looks better to me when I also add the `sn edges` style to the tree. Rather than use the `nice empty nodes` trick of setting `shape` to `coordinate`, this creates phantom content for the empty nodes (just an `X`) and uses a standard text height for all nodes in the tree to keep things aligned.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,calc}

\begin{document}
\newlength\mytextheight
\settototalheight{\mytextheight}{XpX$^0$X$'$}
\begin{forest}
  delay={
    where content={}{
      content={\phantom{X}}
    }{},
  },
  for tree={
    text height=\mytextheight,
    fit=band,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
  }
  [ForceP
    []
    [Force$'$
      [Force$^0$]
      [TopP
        []
        [Top$'$
          [Top$^0$]
          [FocP
            []
            [Foc$'$
              [Foc$^0$]
              [TopP
                []
                [Top$'$
                  [Top$^0$]
                  [FinP
                    []
                    [Fin$'$
                      [Fin$^0$]
                      [IP/AgrSP]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: nicer empty nodes?]

Answer (score 3):

You can define an `nice empty nodes` style as in page 52 of the `forest` manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
nice empty nodes/.style={
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
delay={where content={}{for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={fit=band}
[ForceP, nice empty nodes
        []
        [Force$'$
                [Force$^0$]
                [TopP
                        []
                        [Top$'$
                                [Top$^0$]
                                [FocP
                                        []
                                        [Foc$'$
                                                [Foc$^0$]
                                                [TopP
                                                        []
                                                        [Top$'$
                                                                [Top$^0$]
                                                                [FinP
                                                                        []
                                                                        [Fin$'$
                                                                                [Fin$^0$]
                                                                                [IP/AgrSP]]]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can improve the appearance of `calign=fixed edge angles` by tweaking the angle of the branches (e.g., `calign angle=60`, `calign angle=45`, etc.). This will need to be balanced against horizontal space constraints for the tree, especially if used with `fit=band`.

Comment: The definition of `nice empty nodes` in the `forest` manual includes `shape=coordinate`, which is necessary when the empty nodes are along the spine of the tree. However, there is a bug in `pgf` that sometimes throws an error when you use `sn edges` with that version of `nice empty nodes`. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204094/42880) and the comments under it for a workaround. If you run into the division by 0 error, you can tweak the `sep` values of a `rectangle` node for empty nodes instead of using a `coordinate` node.