# PGF Math error with blank node in forrest

Tags: pgfmath, forest

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}



\forestset{

sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom{}}},

background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,}},   

qtree/.style={
baseline,
for tree={
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
  align=center,
  inner sep=1pt,
}},

nice empty nodes/.style={for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}}

}


\begin{document}


\begin{exe}

\ex

\begin{forest} qtree, nice empty nodes,  

[…, for descendants={l=0}, name=dots , tikz={\node [draw,green,inner sep=12pt, fit=(V)(dots)(book)(Erel)(v)(T)] {};}
[ \emph{v}P
    [DP
        [Erel, triangle, name=Erel ] ]
    [ {}, s sep=5em
        [VP, name=VP, tikz={\node [draw,red,fit to tree] {};}
                [DP
                    [ book-ACC, name=book, triangle ] ] 
                [V\\buy, name=V] ] 
        [\emph{v}, name=v ] ] ]
[T, name=T ] ]

\node at (dots)[above=5ex]{{\bf CP-phase}};

\node at (VP)[below=17ex]{{\bf VP-phase}}; name=VPnod

\end{forest}

\end{exe}
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
./divide with zero.tex:39: Package PGF Math Error: You asked me to calculate `1

/0.0', but I cannot divide any number by zero.


See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.

Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

 ...                                              


l.39 \end{forest}
```

However if I change the empty node under vP to anything, the error is gone.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [sn edges and nice empty nodes styles in forest lead to dividing by zero; what's going on?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204094/42880). This error is due to a bug in `pgf`. The comments on the main question I linked to have some suggestions about a workaround using a node with a size that's almost 0 rather than using a coordinate for the empty nodes.

Comment: @JasonZentz Options: [pretty nice empty nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262577/horizontally-aligned-terminal-nodes-in-trees-with-nice-empty-nodes-using-forest/262689#262689), [my pretty nice empty nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281487/custom-forest-style-dimension-too-large-dividing-by-zero/281546#281546) and [fairly nice empty nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323553/decrease-distance-between-nodes-in-tree-using-forest/323567#323567) styles written by me and Alan Munn.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the comments from the question linked to by @Jason to edit to code in order to solve the problem. The code below resolves the problem with   pgf  , but leaves some white space at the blank node, where the branches almost connects. Using the command below locally to the specific `forest` environment instead of the whole document you can still use the nice empty nodes command for all other trees in the document.

```
calign=fixed edge angles ,delay={where content={}{shape=rectangle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt ,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}


\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{forest} qtree, calign=fixed edge angles ,delay={where content={}{shape=rectangle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt ,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}, 
[\ldots, for descendants={l=0}, name=dots , tikz={\node [draw,green,inner sep=12pt, fit=(V)(dots)(book)(Erel)(v)(T)] {};}
    [ \emph{v}P, s sep=22pt
        [DP
            [Erel, triangle, name=Erel ] ]
        [ {}, s sep=30pt
            [VP, name=VP, tikz={\node [draw,red,fit to tree] {};}
                    [DP
                        [ book-ACC, name=book, triangle ] ] 
                    [V\\buy, name=V] ] 
            [\emph{v}, name=v ] ] ]
    [T, name=T ] ]
\node at (dots)[above=5ex]{{\bf CP-phase}};
\node at (VP)[below=13ex]{{\bf VP-phase}}; name=VPnod
\end{forest}
\end{exe}
```

This is the final result. As you can see the blank node branching to VP and *v* is not fully connected to the branch from the mother node *v*P

[image]

**EDIT**: For a newer post relating to the same type of problem, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323921/example-number-from-bottom-to-top-of-a-tree-in-forest). This solution takes care of the example number and sets it to align with the highest node in the tree instead of aligning with the `ldots` node

Comment: As discussed in the comments under the question I linked to above, there does need to be some whitespace at the empty node. However, it's possible to use a negative value for `inner ysep` such that the gap is only visible when zoomed in really far. You will need to tweak this value to meet your needs -- the exact value will depend on font, font size, and the `calign angle`.

Comment: A few other comments: (i) `\bf` is a deprecated command (use `\textbf{}` or `{\bfseries}` instead). (ii) You don't need to use the manual `s sep` values if you put `fit=band` on the nodes linearly adjacent to your boxes; that will ensure that there is only whitespace below those nodes. Personally, I would put `fit=band` on T too. (iii) I would recommend using `calign=fixed edge angles` and `calign angle=60` within the scope of the `if content={}{put them here}` so that the lines are at appropriate angles, but only leading into and out of empty nodes.

Comment: `pretty nice empty nodes` should avoid the gap if it works as advertised.

Comment: @JasonZentz The whitespace isn't critical. It is the size of the node and that it is a node, not a point, of course. But you can compensate automatically with v.2+ of Forest by using a style which draws the edges ever so slightly differently. This alters the angles very, very slightly, but I think the flaw is less visible than the gap.