# Horizontally aligned terminal nodes in trees with nice empty nodes using forest

Tags: trees, forest

When horizontally aligning terminal nodes in trees using the package forest, I run into problems when I try to use the 'nice empty nodes' option, which makes sure that unlabeled nodes connect (this question relates to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17600/how-to-draw-syntactical-trees-with-parallel-leafs-for-a-natural-language)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
 sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}},
 rectangle tree/.style={
 draw tree stage/.style={
 for root'={
   draw tree box=0,
   draw tree,
   TeX={\tikz{\node {\box0};}},
   }}},
   nice empty nodes/.style={
 for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
 delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children=   
{anchor=north}}}{}}
 }
 }

\begin{document}

\noindent Terminal nodes aligned on one line:

\begin{forest}  baseline, sn edges, rectangle tree, where n 
children=0{tier=word}{},

 [VP$_1$,   [read] [NP$_1$,  [the] [ [note] [PP$_1$ [on the table, 
triangle]]]]] 

\end{forest}

\ \\
This doesn't play nice with nice `nice empty nodes':

\begin{forest}  baseline, sn edges, rectangle tree, where n 
children=0{tier=word}{},

 [VP$_1$, nice empty nodes,  [read] [NP$_1$,  [the] [ [note] [PP$_1$ [on the    
table, triangle]]]]] 

\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: example trees]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome! The manual does indicate that `tier....` may not always work. Although I would have thought it would here. Nonetheless, forest seems to get extremely confused no matter what I try. Your results are actually pretty good compared with what it seems to want to do in slightly variant cases!

Comment: This   `nice empty nodes/.style={
 delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}}
 }` doesn't give such a nice final effect for the children of empty nodes, but at least `tier` works as expected.

Comment: @Gonzalo, thanks for your comment. The following returns what looks like the first tree again, so I think it doesn't fix the issue:




    `\begin{forest}  baseline, sn edges, rectangle tree, where n 
    children=0{tier=word}{},
     [VP$_1$, nice empty nodes/.style={ delay={where content={}
    {shape=coordinate}{}} },  [read] [NP$_1$,  [the] [ [note] [PP$_1$ [on the    
    table, triangle]]]]] 
    \end{forest}`

Comment: What I meant was `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
 sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}},
 rectangle tree/.style={
 draw tree stage/.style={
 for root'={
   draw tree box=0,
   draw tree,
   TeX={\tikz{\node {\box0};}},
   }}},
nice empty nodes/.style={ delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}} } }

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}  baseline, sn edges, rectangle tree, where n 
children=0{tier=word}{},
 [VP$_1$, nice empty nodes,  [read] [NP$_1$,  [the] [ [note] [PP$_1$ [on the    
table, triangle]]]]] 
\end{forest}


\end{document}`

Comment: I've delved into the code and I can confirm that this is a bug. I completely forgot about `tier` alignment when I was developing `fixed (edge) angles` calign method: it is the latter process that destroys the tier alignment. I'll see what I can do to fix this: the problem is harder than it seems ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution which I think comes pretty close to what you want. It is not perfect, but it is hard for me, at least, to see the imperfections. Rather than `nice empty nodes` and `sn edges`, this uses `pretty nice empty nodes` because the empty nodes are not entirely nice, but they are pretty close.

This answer has two versions. The first is for version 2 of **forest**. The second is for version 1. If you use this code, please be sure to choose the appropriate version as neither will work with both versions of the package.

---

## Forest v2

Rather than `shape=coordinate`, we set `inner sep=0pt`. We then alter the `edge path` so that `child anchor=children`. This avoids a tiny gap between the end of one edge and the start of the next. We also set `parent anchor=children` and `calign=fixed edge angles` for the tree but, crucially, we don't use `child anchor=parent` which causes things to go all over the place. (I'm not sure why, but it does.)

[For a south-growing tree, the `parent` anchor is `north` and the `children` anchor is `south`. But if you change the direction of growth, these will adapt accordingly. So these anchors are more flexible than hard-coding the direction as was required in version 1 of the package.]

This means that the lines are not *quite* straight when there is an empty node. But they are very nearly almost straight.

Here's the result:

[image: pretty nice empty nodes 2]

Here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\standaloneenv{forest}
\forestset{
  rectangle tree/.style={
    draw tree stage/.style={
      for root'={
        draw tree box=0,
        draw tree,
        TeX={
          \tikz{\node {\box0};}
        },
      }
    }
  },
  pretty nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles,
      parent anchor=children,
      delay={if content={}{
          inner sep=0pt,
          edge path={\noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.children)\forestoption{edge label};}
        }{}}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 baseline,
 rectangle tree,
 where n children=0{
   tier=word
 }{},
 pretty nice empty nodes
 [VP$_1$
   [read]
   [NP$_1$,
     [the]
     [
       [note]
       [PP$_1$
         [on the table, roof]
       ]
     ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

---

## Forest v1

Rather than `shape=coordinate`, we set `inner sep=0pt`. We then alter the `edge path` so that `child anchor=south`. This avoids a tiny gap between the end of one edge and the start of the next. We also set `parent anchor=south` and `calign=fixed edge angles` for the tree but, crucially, we don't use `child anchor=north` which causes things to go all over the place. (I'm not sure why, but it does.)

This means that the lines are not *quite* straight when there is an empty node. But they are very nearly almost straight.

Here's the result:

[image: pretty nice empty nodes]

Here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\standaloneenv{forest}
\forestset{
  rectangle tree/.style={
    draw tree stage/.style={
      for root'={
        draw tree box=0,
        draw tree,
        TeX={
          \tikz{\node {\box0};}
        },
      }
    }
  },
  pretty nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles,
      parent anchor=south,
      delay={if content={}{
          inner sep=0pt,
          edge path={\noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.south)\forestoption{edge label};}
        }{}}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 baseline,
 rectangle tree,
 where n children=0{
   tier=word
 }{},
 pretty nice empty nodes
 [VP$_1$
   [read]
   [NP$_1$,
     [the]
     [
       [note]
       [PP$_1$
         [on the table, triangle]
       ]
     ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```