# trees with straight spines, and not too much vertical space?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, linguistics, trees

I want to be able to typeset syntactic trees in a way that will achieve the following:

- straight spine when there is no label on the nonterminal node
- obtuse angle at each (binary) branch (so the tree is not too tall)

I'm having trouble making `forest` or (`tikz-`)`qtree` to achieve this easily. Surely there is someone with a solution to this problem out there.

Basically I want to achieve this (**basically what I am asking is: what's some code to output something that looks similar to this:**):

[image: what I want]

but what I get with `tikz-qtree` is

[image: qtree]

which I got using the following code:

```
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree-compat}
    \tikzset{baseline=0pt,level distance=20pt,sibling distance=0pt}
\begin{document}
    \Tree [.CP [.who ] [ [.$\lambda_1$ ]
        [.IP [.$t_1$ ] [.registered ] ] ] ] 
\end{document}
```

or, with `forest`:

[image: forest]

using the following code:

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\newcommand{\tree}[1]{
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
        inner sep=0pt,
        % where n children=0{font=\itshape}{},
     %    calign=fixed edge angles,
        parent anchor=south,
      },
      before typesetting nodes={% page 52: example (81)
        where content={}{% shape=coordinate gives an error if used here but this is *almost* right - it just leaves a little, tiny gap
          text width=.001pt,
          inner sep=0pt,
          before drawing tree={% here we make sure that the tiny gap disappears so only the size is not quite dimensionless
            shape=coordinate,
            typeset node,
          },
          for parent={
            for children={
              anchor=north,
            }
          }
        }{}
      }
      #1
    \end{forest}
}

\begin{document}
    \tree{
        [CP [who] [ [$\lambda_1$] 
        [IP [$t_1$] [registered]]]]
    }
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an easy way of getting nice trees like in the first image (where not all nonterminals have labels, but some do, and the spine is nice and straight, but the trees are not too tall (i.e. distance between levels is small, in particular when the node labels are short. Perhaps another way to state this: lower limit on the angle at each branch, while keeping horizontal distance at a minimum too)?  I imagine this should be a commonly desired thing among linguists. I'd be happy to learn there's an easy way of doing this... thanks!

Comment: You commented out `calign=fixed edge angles,`. Why? And does "no label" mean "no text" or "no edge label"? Could you perhaps try to illustrate this with a drawing?

Comment: `forest` can't do this really. All the options are compromises. See e.g. [A nice empty node with nice nodes in forest?](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/367874), [A nice empty node with nice nodes in forest?](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/367874), [How do I make trees with straight skeletons or spines?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/168807), [Getting straight lines with empty nodes in forest](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/448690). See also ["Kinks" in long tikz-qtree branches](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/260845) for a similar problem with `tikz-qtree`.

Comment: If you have lots of these trees, you may want to consider using the more limited but still usable `qtree`. Of course this limits the other fancier stuff you can do with the trees using the TikZ methods, but depending on your actual needs may be sufficient.

Comment: @marmot "label" here mean no text on a non-terminal node of the tree. It doesn't refer to labels in the TikZ sense (which indeed would be edge labels).

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicate of the first link in my first comment.

Comment: @marmot `calign=fixed edge angles` does make the angles all the same, but in this case they are already the same without this what it really does is narrow the obtuse angles on a tree with long labels.... uncommenting it doesn't get me closer to the thing I want in this case.

Comment: @AlanMunn I want to have the trees be less tall, when they're simple like this (no long node labels).  This means I guess I want obtuse angles.  I can't figure a way to force forest to make something like the first image I shared in the post. I think what I am looking for is to take something like what `forest` gives me, but force the distance between levels to be smaller than the default.

Comment: I have used a version of the `nice empty nodes` style I shared in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216103/42880) that includes `calign angle=60` along with `calign=fixed edge angles`. That will reduce the height of the tree and make the angles more obtuse. But as @AlanMunn notes, you may occasionally run into errors with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used TeX much in the past few years, but I do have existing code that produces the result you're looking for. My `nice trees` style is cobbled together from several sources (some cited below in the code below, likely some not), and I don't think I can explain exactly what every line is doing. If I recall correctly, I would have to switch to `somewhat nice trees` on a per-tree basis if there were "divide by 0" errors (as @AlanMunn indicated in the comments on your question, this has been a perennial topic on the site, and there are no perfect solutions as of yet). Still, I'm sharing because your MWE's tree does compile fine (with your desired requirements met) with `nice trees`. I believe the key for your purposes is `calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=60`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    nice trees/.style={
        for tree={
            parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north,
            align=center,
            base=top,
            inner sep=1pt,
            l-=4ex,
            before typesetting nodes={% based on nice empty nodes - page 52 of the manual, used in Jason Zentz's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216103/
                if content={}{
                    for parent={
                        for children={anchor=north},
                        calign=fixed edge angles,
                        calign angle=60,              
                    },
                    shape=coordinate,
                    calign=fixed edge angles,
                    calign angle=60,       
                }{},
                if n children=0{delay=with translation}{}  % from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205311, in order to reduce the width of triangles/roofs
            },
        },
    },
    somewhat nice trees/.style={
        for tree={
            parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north,
            align=center,
            base=top,
            inner sep=1pt,
            l-=4ex,
            before typesetting nodes={% based on nice empty nodes - page 52 of the manual, used in Jason Zentz's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216103/
                if content={}{
                    for parent={
                        for children={anchor=north},
                        calign=fixed edge angles,
                        calign angle=60,              
                    },
                    inner sep=0pt,
                    edge path={\noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.south)\forestoption{edge label};}, %from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281546
                    calign=fixed edge angles,
                    calign angle=60,       
                }{},
                if n children=0{delay=with translation}{}  % from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205311, in order to reduce the width of triangles/roofs
            },
        },
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
nice trees
        [CP [who] [ [$\lambda_1$] 
        [IP [$t_1$] [registered]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting this answer here. It works for my MWE, indeed, so it’s useful to me. I hope it’s useful to others as well.