# Example number from bottom to top of a Tree in Forest

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-trees, linguistics, forest, gb4e

After a recent update from MacTex 2015 to 2016, the `forest` package also updates, which caused problems for an existing tree had. The problem concerns the example number the `gb4e` package creates. Before the update the number appeared at the same height as the node CP-phase. In this version the example number appears at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{forest, gb4e}

\forestset{
fairly nice empty nodes/.style={
            delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={
                  for children={anchor=north}}}{}}
}}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}


\begin{exe}
\ex \label{saktree1}
\begin{forest}, fairly nice empty nodes, 
[CP-phase, phantom, l sep=19pt, 
    [\ldots, for descendants={l=0}, name=dots, tikz={\node [draw,inner sep=20pt, fit=(V)(dots)(book)(Erel)(v)(T)] {};}
        [\textit{v}P
            [DP
                [Erel, fit=band, roof, name=Erel ] ]
            [{}, calign angle=60
                [VP, name=VP, tikz={\node [draw, inner sep=1pt, fit=(VP)(V)(book)] {};}
                        [DP
                            [ kinige, name=book, roof ] ] 
                        [V\\atyylas-ta, name=V] ] 
                [\textit{v}, name=v, fit=band ] ] ]
        [T, name=T, fit=band ] ] ]
\node at (dots)[above=6ex]{\bfseries{CP-phase}}; baseline
\node at (VP)[below=78pt]{\bfseries{VP-phase}}; name=VPnod
\end{forest}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

The code yields the following output:

[image]

Comment: The problem has something to do with how the `phantom` node is drawn; if you remove that, it aligns again. (Not a solution, just an observation.)  The code for this was changed in the most recent version, so possibly this is a bug.

Comment: Yes, removing the `phantom` makes part of the problem go away, but the example number shows up at the same height as the three dots node and not att the CP-phase node.

Comment: If I remove `phantom` from your code and make the `\node...` command that contains CP phase empty, the number lines up with the CP phase node.

Comment: I can reproduce your result. The only problem that remains is the line between the node containing CP-phase and the node with the dots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `linguistics` library, the root node is automatically set as `baseline`. However (since forest v2.0.3), `baseline` on phantom nodes is ignored --- as it should be, as they are not drawn.

To set the CP-phase (non-forest) node as baseline, one needs to use `tikz`'s key `baseline`. One way to do this, by appending to forest's style `begin draw` and thus providing arguments to the entire `tikzpicture` that forest produces, is shown below.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{forest, gb4e}

\forestset{
fairly nice empty nodes/.style={
            delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={
                  for children={anchor=north}}}{}}
}}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}


\begin{exe}
\ex \label{saktree1}
\begin{forest}, fairly nice empty nodes, 
                begin draw/.append code={[baseline=(CP-phase.base)]},
[CP-phase, phantom, l sep=19pt, 
    [\ldots, for descendants={l=0}, name=dots, tikz={\node [draw,inner sep=20pt, fit=(V)(dots)(book)(Erel)(v)(T)] {};}
        [\textit{v}P
            [DP
                [Erel, fit=band, roof, name=Erel ] ]
            [{}, calign angle=60
                [VP, name=VP, tikz={\node [draw, inner sep=1pt, fit=(VP)(V)(book)] {};}
                        [DP
                            [ kinige, name=book, roof ] ] 
                        [V\\atyylas-ta, name=V] ] 
                [\textit{v}, name=v, fit=band ] ] ]
        [T, name=T, fit=band ] ] ]
\node at (dots)[above=6ex,name=CP-phase]{\bfseries{CP-phase}}; baseline
\node at (VP)[below=78pt]{\bfseries{VP-phase}}; name=VPnod
\end{forest}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

A "historical" note. The interaction between `baseline` and `phantom` was actually buggy pre-2.0.3. OP's example only works because the root, which is placed at `(0,0)`, is the intended baseline.

Also note that the above code nicely aligns the (TeX) baselines of `(1)` and `CP-phase`, while versions prior to 2.0.3 aligned the baseline of `(1)` and the center of `CP-phase`.