# What is the cause of this dimension-too-large error? Occurs with TL2019 but not TL2018 with identical forest.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, texlive, forest, texlive-2019

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle,draw}
  [1[2[3][4]][5]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

With Texlive 2019, I get the following error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@x 

l.28 \end{forest}
```

The code compiles fine with Texlive 2018. (Not sure whether I got the final updates for TL2018). The files `forest.sty` are identical in TL2018 and TL2019.

What's changed to cause the error? Is it a bug? If so, in what and where?

Comment: That's really odd. If one drops, say, `[4]`, the error is gone.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, I know. Or `circle`.

Comment: Though you could drop `draw`, so the example isn't ideally minimal.

Comment: `for tree={circle,draw,rotate=1}` also removes the error. Rotating a circle helps? Strange. ;-) If you rotate by `45`, `90`, `180` or so on, the error comes back.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Even rotating the circles by `0.1` removes it.

Comment: Anything but a integer multiple of `45` seems to work....

Comment: The same happen with recent MikTeX.

Comment: @Zarko Weird, isn't it?

Comment: @cfr, yes, it is. No so long ago I wrote similar `forest` tree and it has worked. I do not know with which MikTeX upgrade this change.

Comment: I think I may have isolated the error: it seems to come from the lines `\divide\c@pgf@counta by 255\relax%
          \pgf@ya=16\pgf@ya\relax%
          \divide\pgf@ya by\c@pgf@counta%
          \pgf@xa=16\pgf@ya\relax%` in `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat A diff of the 2018 and 2019 file doesn't include the word `divide` so those lines in themselves haven't changed. (Which doesn't mean that's not where the error's coming from, of course.)

Comment: I only found that if I remove this the error goes away. But you are right, adding `\typeout`s does not reveal anything that is very different when one adds small rotation angle. The error is not necessarily in the `\divide` but perhaps in the `\pgf@x=\pgf@xa%` that follows, but I cannot see how `\pgf@xa` is too large. (Unfortunately I cannot do a diff because I do not have the older versions available.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat https://pastebin.com/Btuh8UZ4

Comment: Can you copy the old file `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex` to the directory in which you compile the document? Does that help?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Scratch my last comment. I left a `rotate` in my code. Dropping that file in doesn't help. The error stays the same.

Comment: There have been some changes in pgf's floating point unit, maybe that's the culprit.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I appreciate your looking.

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but it seems so be related to `intersections`. If I add `\tracingmacros=1`, at the very end before the error one finds `\pgf@intersect@len@a ` which comes from the pgf module intersections. A bit above one finds `\pgfmathresult ->{-619.9691000000000}{2904.08000000000}` which become `\pgfmathresult ->{119.74692000000000}{-559.422000000000}` for `rotate=0.1`. @SašoŽivanović And it is true that right before there is `\pgfmathfloattofixed@impl@pos`. So maybe this is some interplay between intersections and floating point numbers?

Comment: @cfr That was not looking, but guessing. ;-)  I'm afraid I'm not at my desktop this weekend, and I still have TeXLive 2018 on my laptop ...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, intersections are heavy users of fpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that ultimately, the error occurs for the same reason as with `nice empty nodes` style: `\pgfintersectionofpaths` yields an error when the lines it is trying to intersect are almost parallel. See [the original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204094/16819) on this issue and [the bug report](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/369) in PGF's GitHub repo.

In this case, the trigger for the error seems to be the improved version of PGF'S `\pgfpointnormalised` (introduced in commit 65b8261c, released in PGF 3.1.2), which is called from the declaration of shape `circle` in `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`. It makes sense: a more precise function yields more nearly parallel lines and thus makes the intersecting fail more often.

(The bug report on `\pgfintersectionofpaths` is open for four years now but had not yet been addressed. For a good reason, I guess, as it seems a very hard issue to fix, certainly above my league. I hope the new "application" of the bug encourages work on it. I'm adding a link to this answer to the bug report.)

Comment: Thanks. I hope so, too. This is a pretty surprising thing to fail :(.

Comment: Salvation might be close! See the development in the bug report.

Comment: Brilliant - shame they can't use your patch :(.