# How do I draw Phrase Structure Trees in the Style of Heim & Kratzer (1998)?

Tags: linguistics, trees

I'm trying to figure out how to draw simple syntactic trees like the ones here, found in Heim & Kratzer's "Semantics & Generative Grammar." I do not want to include labels such as NP, VP, etc., and I will also need to be able to include more branching than in the examples shown here. Thanks for your help!

[image: Example image]

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a question that will only make sense to a very tiny portion of the community here. The two major tree drawing packages `tikz-qtree` and `forest` both allow n-ary branching trees and arbitrary label text. (You will need to enclose the labels in `{...}` if they have more content). So perhaps you should try to reproduce a tree from Heim and Kratzer in a minimal document, add your attempt to your question and ask about what you are having trouble with specifically.

Comment: @AlanMunn Or the OP could arrange for Amazon to mail all interested members of the site a copy.

Comment: @cfr Since I happen to have a copy of Heim and Kratzer handy, the question is even more mysterious since most of their trees have labels (although some are unlablelled) and all are binary branching.

Comment: @AlanMunn Scotch my suggestion, then. Global distribution of the book to all TeX SE members doesn't sound as if it would help.

Comment: Also @cfr 's answer to this question: [How do I make trees with straight skeletons or spines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168807) should be helpful.

Comment: @AlanMunn Is there an answer which might help using current Forest? My answer there doesn't use `linguistics` because it didn't exist at the time, but I'm not sure what about that answer you think helpful as I don't have the book.

Comment: @AlanMunn Ahh I'm so sorry! I thought I uploaded the screenshot of what I had in mind. I didn't realize it didn't go through.

Comment: Well code of what you had tried would have also been appreciated. But cfr and I seemed to be in a generous mood. :)  But I assume our answers cover the cases you need.?

Answer (score 3):

Since I happen to have a copy of Heim and Kratzer handy, your question is even more mysterious since most of their trees have labels (although some are unlablelled) and all are binary branching. Here's a tree using the `forest` package to get you started:

I've used the `nice empty nodes` style to allow labelless nodes, and created a `pad` style for nodes that are very small (like the `1` node). The `calign with current` addition to the DP node flattens the VP tree (without it, the tree looks quite ugly). [Thanks to cfr for that code.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{pad/.style={minimum width=5em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}nice empty nodes
[S  
    [ {every linguist} ] 
    [ [1,pad ]  [S [ John ] 
                [   [T,pad ]  
                    [VP [V\\introduced ] 
                        [DP\\$t_{1}$,calign with current ] 
                        [PP\\{to Mary}]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Alternatively, if you don't mind how straight the empty node branches are, then you can use a slightly different definition for the empty nodes. This is probably better with non-binary trees. (And doesn't need the manual fixup in the DP node.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{pad/.style={minimum width=5em},
    empty nodes/.style={
            delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={
                  for children={anchor=north}}}{}}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} empty nodes
[S  
    [ {every linguist} ] 
    [ [1,pad]  [S [ John ] 
                [   [T,pad]  
                    [VP [V\\introduced, ] 
                        [DP\\$t_{1}$ ] 
                        [PP\\{to Mary}]
                    ]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: (+1) For Forest 2. I'm not sure `nice empty nodes` is a good idea unless the tree is at least primarily binary branching.

Answer (score 2):

'More branching' is ambiguous. You might mean that you need some nodes to have more than 2 children or you might mean that you just need more binary branches.

In the second case, just using the `linguistics` library with `nice empty nodes` will do a lot for your tree. In the first case, however, `nice empty nodes` will cause problems. If your tree is mostly binary, as in AlanMunn's example, then overriding its effects on an *ad hoc* basis is a reasonable option. If, however, it diverges much further, you are better off not using `nice empty nodes` here at all.

Here's an adaption of Alan's example which demonstrates the problem.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{pad/.style={minimum width=5em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  nice empty nodes
  [S
    [{every linguist}
    ]
    [
      [1, pad
      ]
      [Additional thing]
      [Other thing]
      [S
        [ John
        ]
        [
          [T, pad
          ]
          [VP
            [V\\introduced
            ]
            [DP\\$t_{1}$, calign with current
            ]
            [PP\\{to Mary}
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: not very binary]

In this case, `calign with current` is not much help since we'll get either

[image: no better]

[image: also no better]

There are two problems here. One is that there are an even number of children so there is no middle child to align with the parent. The other is that the non-binary branching is not restricted to terminal nodes of the tree.

It might be better in such cases to try to make the empty nodes `less ugly` rather than `nice`. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  pad/.style={minimum width=5em},
  less ugly empty nodes/.style={%
    nice empty nodes,
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where={(n_children())>2}{%
        if={isodd(n_children())}{%
          for n={int((n_children()+1)/2)}{calign with current},
        }{%
          for n={int((n_children())/2)}{insert after={[,phantom,calign with current]}},
        },
        if nodewalk valid={uu}{%
          if={(n_children("!u")<3)&&(n_children("!uu")>2)}{!u.calign=midpoint}{},
        }{%
          if nodewalk valid=u{%
            !u.calign=midpoint,
          }{},
        },
      }{},
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  less ugly empty nodes
  [S
    [{every linguist}
    ]
    [
      [1, pad
      ]
      [Additional\\thing]
      [Other\\thing]
      [S
        [ John
        ]
        [
          [T, pad
          ]
          [VP
            [V\\introduced
            ]
            [DP\\$t_{1}$
            ]
            [PP\\{to Mary}
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: less ugly empty nodes]

This doesn't do too badly even with really quite crazy-looking trees.

[image: quite crazy-looking tree]

```
\begin{forest}
  less ugly empty nodes
  [S
    [{every linguist}
    ]
    [wants]
    [
      [1, pad
      ]
      [Additional\\thing]
      [Other\\thing]
      [S
        [ John
        ]
        [
          [T, pad
          ]
          [VP
            [V\\introduced
            ]
            [DP\\$t_{1}$
            ]
            [PP\\{to Mary}
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [to be
      [a]
      [philosopher
        [every philosopher
          [wants]
          [
            [to]
            [be]
            [a
              [mathematician]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Ideally, I guess the code would test for craziness and adjust automatically. However, that answer would need a different and hopefully somewhat clearer question.