# Remove white space from empty nodel label in tikz-qtree?

Tags: spacing, nodes, tikz-qtree

With empty nodes in `tikz-qtree` how do I remove the white space where the node label usually appears? In the following example I want to remove the white space for the node under Foot 3.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=145pt}}
\Tree [.Line [.Colon1 [.Metron1 [.Foot1 (A) B ] [.Foot2 A B ] ] [.Metron2 [.Foot3 [.\node {}; B A ] B ] ] ] [.Colon2 [.Metron3 [.Foot4  [.\node {}; (B) A ] B ] ] [.Metron4 [.Foot5 [.\node {}; B A ] B ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not know how to compile that. Please give us a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check out these related questions: [macro for empty nodes in tikz-qtree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58972/42880), [How do I make trees with straight skeletons or spines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168807/42880), and [Making mixed trees with and without text-containing nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35112/42880).

Answer (score 1):

Control the `inner sep` and `outer sep` like

```
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-0.4pt] {};
```

Here 0.4pt is the `\pgflinewidth` without which a small separtion appears. Another option is to use

```
\node[shape=coordinate] {};
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=145pt}}
\Tree [.Line [.Colon1 [.Metron1 [.Foot1 (A) B ] [.Foot2 A B ] ] [.Metron2 [.Foot3 [.\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-0.4pt] {}; B A ] B ] ] ] [.Colon2 [.Metron3 [.Foot4  [.\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-0.4pt] {}; (B) A ] B ] ] [.Metron4 [.Foot5 [.\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-0.4pt] {}; B A ] B ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]